# File Name is incorrect in Directory

Tags: files-and-directories

This is my test.

```
x = 1.;
file2 = "sqrt2_2b.txt";
Do[x = x/2 + 1/x; x >>> file2, {5}]
```

This code above I get the File name **"file2"**. However, this code below will give me the name I want.

```
x = 1.;
Do[x = x/2 + 1/x; x >>> "sqrt2_2b.txt", {5}]
```

This will give File Name **"sqrt2_2b.txt"**.

Using

```
x = 1.;
file2 = sqrt2_2b.txt 
Do[x = x/2 + 1/x; x >>> file2, {5}]
```

is not working either.

Why is this? Could anyone explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 3):

Use `PutAppend[x, file2]`.  See [`PutAppend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PutAppend.html).

The `<<`, `>>`, and `>>>` operators are special and treat their second operand as a string.  `x >>> y` means `PutAppend[x, "y"]` and not `PutAppend[x, y]`.

Comment: However, using `file2 = sqrt2_2b.txt` is not working either.

Comment: @kile I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You should use `file2 = "sqrt2_2b.txt"`. If what I suggested does not work (it does for me), please add a complete minimal example to the question.

Comment: It must be said: this is definitely one of the wonkiest syntax issues in WL.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have edited my question. I hope you can understand me now.

Comment: @kile As I said above, use `file2 = "sqrt2_2b.txt"`. I am not sure why you would expect `file2 = sqrt2_2b.txt` to work.